# Unable to load the specified metadata resource,posgressql and entityframework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

Im mapping a view using entity framework and a postgresql view but i get 
Unable to load the specified metadata resource error,

here what i am doing :

```
 public class Custumers
{
    [Table("v_at_customers", Schema = "zd")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("customer_id")]
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public string organization { get; set; }

    }
}
```

}

DbContext:

```
 public partial class db_Entities : DbContext
    {
    public db_Entities()
        : base("name=LTW")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

here is where i get the error in controller:

```
 db_Entities dt = new db_Entities();


        var s=(from t in dt.Customer
              select new 
              {

               Customeress=dt.customer_id

              }).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I marked the places where you need to be careful with yellow

usage package:

[image]

config file:

[image]

dbcontext:

[image]

result:

[image]